# why does matplotlib-cpp throw runtime exceptions in the 3d examples

Tags: c++, matplotlib

Experimenting with https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp.  I have python 3.10.10, numpy 1.24.2, and matplotlib 3.7.1

The author of matplotlib-cpp does not publish releases.  I was using the current version on 2023-04-21 (commit ef038).

When I build the 'surface' example (per the authors instructions) and run the resulting executable, I get this:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
> what():  No axis
> [1]    17416 IOT instruction (core dumped)

Reports in the github issues discussion seem to indicate that some people have success running the matplotlib-cpp examples out of the box.

For me, the 2d examples seem to work.  However, the 3d examples all fail as described above.

I tried a few changes suggested in the github issues discussion, but nothing helped.

Edit: here's the backtrace from gcc

```
 (gdb) bt
#0 __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=, signo=signo@entry=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0)
at pthread_kill.c:44
#1 0x00007ffff74a0953 in __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=) at pthread_kill.c:78
#2 0x00007ffff7451ea8 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#3 0x00007ffff743b53d in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#4 0x00007ffff769a833 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler ()
at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#5 0x00007ffff76a6d0c in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=)
at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:48
#6 0x00007ffff76a6d79 in std::terminate () at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:58
#7 0x00007ffff76a6fdd in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=,
tinfo=0x555555562d60 <typeinfo for std::runtime_error@GLIBCXX_3.4>,
dest=0x7ffff76be480 std::runtime_error::~runtime_error())
at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:98
#8 0x000055555555a369 in matplotlibcpp::plot_surface (x=std::vector of length 41, capacity 64 = {...},
y=std::vector of length 41, capacity 64 = {...}, z=std::vector of length 41, capacity 64 = {...},
keywords=std::map with 0 elements, fig_number=0) at ../matplotlibcpp.h:567
#9 0x00005555555569e7 in main () at surface.cpp:22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what has happened is that the matplotlib API has changed since matplotlib-cpp was last updated.

In recent matplotlib versions, one does not pass `projection=3d` to the `gca()` function.  Instead, one should explicitly create a subplot with `add_subplot(projection=3d)`.

The attached patch fixes the surface, quiver, and lines3d examples for me.

I've factored out a chunk of code that was cut/pasted in 4 places and made it a new function.  Inside that function I implement the fix I've described.  However, I chose to keep the call to `gca()` even though I think it is redundant.

```
  diff --git a/matplotlibcpp.h b/matplotlibcpp.h
  index d95d46a..da7568d 100644
  --- a/matplotlibcpp.h
  +++ b/matplotlibcpp.h
  @@ -470,6 +470,31 @@ bool plot(const std::vector<Numeric> &x, const std::vector<Numeric> &y, const st
       return res;
   }

  +//Given a figure, create a subplot with a 3d axis and return a pointer to that axis. also calls incref on the axis pointer.
  +PyObject* init_3d_axis(PyObject *fig)
  +{
  +  PyObject *asp_kwargs = PyDict_New();
  +  PyDict_SetItemString(asp_kwargs, "projection", PyString_FromString("3d"));
  +
  +  PyObject *asp = PyObject_GetAttrString(fig, "add_subplot");
  +  Py_INCREF(asp);
  +  PyObject *tmpax = PyObject_Call(asp, detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_empty_tuple, asp_kwargs);
  +  Py_INCREF(tmpax);
  +
  +  PyObject *gca = PyObject_GetAttrString(fig, "gca");
  +  if (!gca) throw std::runtime_error("No gca");
  +  Py_INCREF(gca);
  +  PyObject *axis = PyObject_Call(gca, detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_empty_tuple, detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_empty_tuple);
  +
  +  if (!axis) throw std::runtime_error("No axis");
  +  Py_INCREF(axis);
  +
  +  Py_DECREF(gca);
  +  Py_DECREF(tmpax);
  +  Py_DECREF(asp);
  +  return axis;
  +}
  +
   // TODO - it should be possible to make this work by implementing
   // a non-numpy alternative for `detail::get_2darray()`.
   #ifndef WITHOUT_NUMPY
  @@ -554,21 +579,8 @@ void plot_surface(const std::vector<::std::vector<Numeric>> &x,
     }
     Py_DECREF(fig_exists);
     if (!fig) throw std::runtime_error("Call to figure() failed.");
  -
  -  PyObject *gca_kwargs = PyDict_New();
  -  PyDict_SetItemString(gca_kwargs, "projection", PyString_FromString("3d"));
  -
  -  PyObject *gca = PyObject_GetAttrString(fig, "gca");
  -  if (!gca) throw std::runtime_error("No gca");
  -  Py_INCREF(gca);
  -  PyObject *axis = PyObject_Call(
  -      gca, detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_empty_tuple, gca_kwargs);
  -
  -  if (!axis) throw std::runtime_error("No axis");
  -  Py_INCREF(axis);
  -
  -  Py_DECREF(gca);
  -  Py_DECREF(gca_kwargs);
  +
  +  PyObject *axis = init_3d_axis(fig);

     PyObject *plot_surface = PyObject_GetAttrString(axis, "plot_surface");
     if (!plot_surface) throw std::runtime_error("No surface");
  @@ -723,20 +735,7 @@ void plot3(const std::vector<Numeric> &x,
     }
     if (!fig) throw std::runtime_error("Call to figure() failed.");

  -  PyObject *gca_kwargs = PyDict_New();
  -  PyDict_SetItemString(gca_kwargs, "projection", PyString_FromString("3d"));
  -
  -  PyObject *gca = PyObject_GetAttrString(fig, "gca");
  -  if (!gca) throw std::runtime_error("No gca");
  -  Py_INCREF(gca);
  -  PyObject *axis = PyObject_Call(
  -      gca, detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_empty_tuple, gca_kwargs);
  -
  -  if (!axis) throw std::runtime_error("No axis");
  -  Py_INCREF(axis);
  -
  -  Py_DECREF(gca);
  -  Py_DECREF(gca_kwargs);
  +  PyObject *axis = init_3d_axis(fig);

     PyObject *plot3 = PyObject_GetAttrString(axis, "plot");
     if (!plot3) throw std::runtime_error("No 3D line plot");
  @@ -1126,20 +1125,7 @@ bool scatter(const std::vector<NumericX>& x,
     Py_DECREF(fig_exists);
     if (!fig) throw std::runtime_error("Call to figure() failed.");

  -  PyObject *gca_kwargs = PyDict_New();
  -  PyDict_SetItemString(gca_kwargs, "projection", PyString_FromString("3d"));
  -
  -  PyObject *gca = PyObject_GetAttrString(fig, "gca");
  -  if (!gca) throw std::runtime_error("No gca");
  -  Py_INCREF(gca);
  -  PyObject *axis = PyObject_Call(
  -      gca, detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_empty_tuple, gca_kwargs);
  -
  -  if (!axis) throw std::runtime_error("No axis");
  -  Py_INCREF(axis);
  -
  -  Py_DECREF(gca);
  -  Py_DECREF(gca_kwargs);
  +  PyObject *axis = init_3d_axis(fig);

     PyObject *plot3 = PyObject_GetAttrString(axis, "scatter");
     if (!plot3) throw std::runtime_error("No 3D line plot");
  @@ -1503,19 +1489,7 @@ bool quiver(const std::vector<NumericX>& x, const std::vector<NumericY>& y, cons
                             detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_empty_tuple);
     if (!fig) throw std::runtime_error("Call to figure() failed.");

  -  PyObject *gca_kwargs = PyDict_New();
  -  PyDict_SetItemString(gca_kwargs, "projection", PyString_FromString("3d"));
  -
  -  PyObject *gca = PyObject_GetAttrString(fig, "gca");
  -  if (!gca) throw std::runtime_error("No gca");
  -  Py_INCREF(gca);
  -  PyObject *axis = PyObject_Call(
  -      gca, detail::_interpreter::get().s_python_empty_tuple, gca_kwargs);
  -
  -  if (!axis) throw std::runtime_error("No axis");
  -  Py_INCREF(axis);
  -  Py_DECREF(gca);
  -  Py_DECREF(gca_kwargs);
  +  PyObject *axis = init_3d_axis(fig);

     //plot our boys bravely, plot them strongly, plot them with a wink and clap
     PyObject *plot3 = PyObject_GetAttrString(axis, "quiver");
```